# SFINAE - detect if type T is pointer, array or container with random access operator and for given value type

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-keyword, sfinae, random-access

I am fighting with SFINAE trying to have many functions that requires just to have access to the type T with operator `[]`.
So far I have the following code that compiles and works fine with Visual Studio 2017:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

template <typename T,  typename X = std::enable_if_t <std::is_array<T>::value || std::is_pointer<T>::value> > 
void DoIt(T& c)
{}

template <typename T, typename std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<std::random_access_iterator_tag,
typename std::iterator_traits<typename T::iterator>::iterator_category>::value, bool> = true >
void DoIt(T& c)
{}


int main() 
{
    int* a; 
    const int* ac;
    int b[10];
    array<int,6> c;
    vector<int> d;
    string s;

    DoIt(a);   // Ok, compile pass
    DoIt(ac);  // Ok, compile pass
    DoIt(b);   // Ok, compile pass
    DoIt(c);   // Ok, compile pass
    DoIt(d);   // Ok, compile pass
    DoIt(s);   // Ok, compile pass

    int i;
    float f;
    map<int, int> m;

    //DoIt(f);  // Ok, compile fails
    //DoIt(i);  // Ok, compile fails
   // DoIt(m);  // Ok, compile fails
    return 0;
}
```

Now I need the following :

1. How to combine both SFINAE conditions checking for array & pointer and random access operator into one check?
   I have many functions and it is not convenient and too much code to have two declarations. But I somehow failed to combine the conditions in a single `std::enable_if_t` or in a template structure.
2. Is it possible above to be extended and to check also and for the container type, so that for example:

```
    vector<int> a;
    vector<string> b;
    int* c;
    string* d;
    DoIt(a);  // must pass 
    DoIt(c);  // must pass
    DoIt(b);  // must fail
    DoIt(d);  // must fail
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to combine both SFINAE conditions checking for array & pointer and random access operator into one check? I

The simplest way that come in my mind is check if you can write `c[0u]`

```
template <typename T>
auto DoIt(T& c) -> decltype( c[0u], void() )
{}
```

Not a perfect solution: works with types accepting an unsigned integer for as argument for `operator[]` (`std::vector`s, `std::array`s, C-style arrays, pointers, `std::map`s with an integer key) but fails with maps with keys incompatibles with unsigned integers.

You can reduce this problem adding a template parameter for the key type (defaulting it to `std::size_t`)

```
template <typename K = std::size_t, typename T>
auto DoIt(T& c) -> decltype( c[std::declval<K>()], void() )
{}
```

so works as follows

```
std::array<int,6> c;

DoIt(c);   // Ok, compile pass, no needs to explicit the key type

std::map<std::string, int> m;

DoIt(m);   // compilation error: std::size_t is a wrong key type
DoIt<std::string>(m);  // Ok, compile: std::string is a good key type
```

If you want enable the function checking also the type returned by the operator `[]`... well... conceptually is simple but require a little typewriting

I propose the following `DoIt2()` function where you have to explicit the required type for operator `[]` and `std::size_t` remain the default type for the argument of the operator (but you can explicit a different type)

```
template <typename V, typename K = std::size_t, typename T>
std::enable_if_t<
   std::is_same_v<V,
      std::remove_const_t<
         std::remove_reference_t<
            decltype(std::declval<T>()[std::declval<K>()])>>>>
   DoIt2 (T &)
 {}
```

The idea is simple: get the type of `std::declval<T>()[std::declval<K>()]`, remove reference (if present), remove `const` (if present) and check if the resulting type is equal to `V` (the requested type)

You can use `DoIt2()` as follows

```
std::vector<int>   v1;
std::vector<float> v2;

DoIt2<int>(v1);    // compile
//DoIt2<int>(v2);  // compilation error

//DoIt2<float>(v1);  // compilation error
DoIt2<float>(v2);    // compile

std::map<int, std::string>    m1;
std::map<std::string, float>  m2;

DoIt2<std::string, int>(m1);
DoIt2<float, std::string>(m2);
```

Comment: Yes. thanks, fails for map<int, int> but otherwise may works. How to check also that c[0u]  is for example int or char*?

Comment: @BajMile - well, not exactly: works with `map<int, int>`; fails with `map<std::string, int>`; answer improved.

Comment: @BajMile - regarding the type of `c[0u]` (or better: `c[std::declval<K>()]`)... you can use `decltype()`:  `decltype( c[std::declval<K>()] )`

Comment: I still can't get how to check the array type, for example int*, vector<int> to pass but float*, vector<float> to fail. Can you give example?

Comment: @BajMile - sorry... I don't understand your problem... please, can you explain what you want with some examples?

Comment: @BajMile - maybe I understand... do you want a SFINAE check so that `DoIt()` compile if `c[std::declval<K>]` is (by example) of type `int` (maybe a type of a template parameter) but fails when `c[std::declval<K>]` is a type different than `int`?

Comment: Yes, something like that. These functions are members of a template class of lets say type T. Now I have two function declarations for T* and vector<T>,  and T**, vector<T*>, etc. I want to remove one of them, your solution will work, but how to check if array value type is at all T?

Comment: @BajMile - answer improved; hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work so generally this answers my question as asked. To be able to use it in template class - is it allowed to put all conditions inside template list declaration - template <typename T, typename K = std::size_t, typename C, typename 
    X = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,
    std::remove_const_t<
    std::remove_reference_t<
    decltype(std::declval<C>()[std::declval<K>()])>>>>
>

Comment: This would allow and any return type?

Comment: @BajMile - For return type... sure. The type returned by `std::enable_if`; so `void` by default, `decltype(std::declval<T>()[std::declval<K>()])>>>, DifferentReturnType>` otherwise.

Comment: Ok, just one last thing - can I use for shorter rather std::decay_t instead of  std::remove_const_t< std::remove_reference_t, I am trying to understand difference but seems to works too.

Comment: @BajMile - `std::decay`... let me think... no, I suppose you get a false positive in case of a function type: transform it in a pointer to function that, as pointer, support operator `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a bunch of conditional SFINAE that you want to apply, I usually try to split them up in smaller helper structs.

In yoyur example it would look something like this.

```
template <typename T, typename U = void>
struct random_access : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct random_access<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::random_access_iterator_tag,
typename std::iterator_traits<typename T::iterator>::iterator_category>>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
struct random_access<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<T> || std::is_array_v<T>>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool random_access_v = random_access<T>::value;

template <typename T, typename U = void>
struct contains_container : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct contains_container<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::void_t<decltype(std::declval<T&>()[0][0])>, void>>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool contains_container_v = contains_container<T>::value;

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<random_access_v<T> && !contains_container_v<T>, bool> = true>
void DoIt(T&) {}
```

The `contains_container` was my attemp at solving our second part. Not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for, but it checks if two layers of `operator[]` can be applied to `T`. That would make your second examples pass.

Comment: I couldn't compile this with VS2017. Also int* was just example, it should work for any type T- float*, or char**...

Comment: @BajMile It requires `c++17`, but only for the use of `std::is_same_v<...>` instead of `typename std::is_same<...>::value` etc. A few re-writes and it works for `c++11` as well. Not sure what you mean by your second sentence. This works for all the test cases that you have posted in your question. Even the ones in part 2.

Comment: @BajMile Here is a [working example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6x640L0vfR3X0LFD)